# If "nice" is an adjective, what kind of word is "niceness"?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech

Say you have the adjective "nice". If something is nice, then it has the quality of niceness. What type of word is "niceness"? Is it still an adjective?

Comment: Isn't *niceness* the quality of being *nice*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *[nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization)*, the result of making a noun out a word that isn't a noun.  In this case, the word is the adjective *nice*, and the resulting noun *niceness* is the quality of being nice.  In English we do this by making a morphological (i.e., form) change, in this case by adding the suffix
*-ness*.  There are a number of ways to do this:

> *difficult* (adjective) -> *difficult**y*** (noun)
>   *normalize* (verb) -> *normaliz**ation*** (noun)

Comment: zero derivation is also common, like with " good" and "bad."

Comment: Just what I was after, thank you. On a side note, what would the nominalisation of "holophrastic" be? "Holophrasticity"?

Comment: @DogLover I think the noun *holophrasis* came first, and the adjective *holophrastic* was formed from the noun.